# Python module layout where subdirectory name is the same as file

Tags: python, package

I am used to a scripting language where it is very common to lay out modules like so:

```
lib/Foo.pm
lib/Foo/Bar.pm
lib/Foo/Baz.pm
```

Where you have Foo.pm, then there is a directory called Foo and underneath you place submodules.

In Python, I tried to mimic the layout like so:

```
modules/foo.py
modules/foo/bar.py
modules/foo/baz.py
```

However, this wouldn't work because when I do:

```
from foo import Foo
```

Python thinks I'm importing a directory named 'foo' rather than foo.py.  I tried to mess with **init**.py business to no avail.

Is there a way to get around this issue?  I find it quite annoying that Python cannot distinguish between directory foo vs file foo.py.

EDIT:
I think I was missing an important piece.  I am sourcing the modules/ directory via my unit tests, so the entire directory structure looks like so:

```
modules/foo.py
modules/foo/bar.py
modules/foo/baz.py
tests/unit.py
```

In unit.py, I have the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

findbin = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
sys.path.append(findbin + "/../modules")

from foo import Foo

obj = Foo()
```

When I run this, I get:

```
from foo import Foo
ImportError: cannot import name Foo
```

Comment: where are you giving the `from foo import Foo` command?  what makes you think Python thinks you're importing a directory?

Comment: what is Foo? A class?

Comment: Yes, Foo is a class.  class Foo(object):

Comment: If unit.py is outside module you will need to make module a package as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* do this:

```
modules/foo/__init__.py  # instead of foo.py
modules/foo/bar.py
modules/foo/baz.py
```

Perl's layout doesn't work; if a module has children, the root lives alongside them.

And for what it's worth, some Python devs feel strongly that you should leave `__init__.py` empty (or at least minimal), since it's imported first anytime you import any of the children.

It's possible you're also having some other problems if `__init__.py` didn't work for you, especially if you literally have a `modules/` directory, but I can't diagnose without more details  :)

---

Aha.  **DO NOT** mess with `sys.path`; that's *always* a sign you're making life harder for yourself.  (Do you have to mess with `sys.path` to import anyone else's code?  Then why should you have to do it for your own, when it's right there?)

Just put them directly in the root of your source tree, as `project.git/foo/bar.py`.  As long as you run your test harness (or whatever) from your root, you can import them with no problems.

You might also want to try a test library like [pytest](http://pytest.org/) which does discovery and some various fancy things for you.

See also: [Filesystem structure of a Python project](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html)

Or a smallish project of mine for a more practical example: https://github.com/eevee/dywypi

Comment: I added more context on how I am loading the modules/ directory from unit test.  Yes, this is very Perlish way of doing things :-)

Comment: Well, to answer why messing with sys.path is because it is usually easy to derive where the modules are from my tests.  By messing with sys.path, my tests will always load the modules correctly no matter how you run it.  This is very common in Perl where you use FindBin.

Comment: In Python world, how do you manage modules for large project when you do root/foo/bar.py approach?  It becomes increasingly difficult to tell which directory contains your modules, when you have bin/, tests/, foo/, perhaps bar/, baz/ all sitting on project root.

Comment: the module root has the same name as the project, so it's usually pretty obvious.  plus `bin` is obviously not it, and i put the tests inside the package namespace, so i rarely have more than two or three directories in my root.

Comment: and with the project above i just run `py.test`, and it finds all my tests and runs them for me.  the current directory is automatically part of `sys.path` (or, if you're running a script, the script's containing directory — which is why you don't want to directly run `tests/unit.py` like you're doing now  :))

Comment: Right.  Well, in my case where you run unit.py doesn't matter.  I think running py.test is sort of like running prove -r t/* in Perl world.  Not that you care, but I'm just used to it :-)

Comment: fwiw, i used to do perl and there was a bit of a culture shock  :)

Comment: I like both languages.  There is no doubt Python is more readable, but I never understood the purpose of __init__.py, especially when best practices tell it to leave it empty.

Comment: stylistic choice, mostly.  in perl i sometimes found it awkward. that `Foo::Bar` and `Foo::quux` look like siblings, but are in different directories.  the reasons to keep it empty are specific to how Python importing works though

Answer (score 5):

What you want to create is packages.

in the folder `foo` put a blank file with the name `__init__.py`. Python will then treat foo as a package. If `modules` is also to be treated as a package put a blank `__init__.py` inside it as well.

So from your question, if the packages are done correctly and you have this structure:

```
modules/__init__.py
modules/foo/__init__.py
modules/foo/bar.py
modules/foo/baz.py
```

You can do these:

```
import module
from module import foo
from module.foo import bar
import module.foo.bar as foobar
```

And a lot of other stuffs!

Comment: I *think* I have tried that, but let me verify again and see how it goes.

Comment: Oh I see what you're doing.  I didn't want 'module' to be the package name though, as I am using it to only indicate that modules live under there (sort of like 'lib' directory).  But point taken with regard to __init__.py.

Comment: Thing is making module a package is not necessary if you are importing in a file inside module. It is necessary otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Creating packages with Python can be done using `__init__.py` files, but it's important to understand the import priority.  The command

```
from foo import Foo
```

will look for something named `foo` in `sys.path` and then look for something named `Foo` "inside" `foo`.  For example, suppose you did not have any `__init__.py` files in your directory `foo` and your `foo.py` file contains,

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        print 'hello'
```

Giving the command `from foo import Foo` from the module directory will work.

```
>>> from foo import Foo
>>> f = Foo()
hello
```

If you want the directory `foo` to be a package (i.e. a collection of related modules) then you can put an empty `__init__.py` file in the `foo` directory. This however will make the `import` command ambiguous.  I haven't found any documentation that claims packages have higher import priority than modules, but you can verify that Python is importing the package by doing the following,

```
import foo
>>> foo.__file__
foo/__init__.py
```

which means the package got imported.  I imagine the fact that packages have priority will not always be the case.  In the end it's best to remove the name conflict by renaming either the file or the package.

Comment: Even when you have a directory named 'foo' where you have foo.py?  My experience has been that it doesn't work, and that's preventing me from doing Perlish directory layout.

Comment: you can't have both, and you can't trick Python into adopting Perl semantics.  not in this particular case, anyway  :D

Comment: Yeah...I think that's the bottom line.  Python does not allow foo.py and directory foo to co-exist.